# multivariable function as a function over a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

Given a function $f(x_1,x_2)$ in, say, two variables $x_1$, $x_2$, is it right to equivalently represent $f$ as $f(\mathbf{X})$ where $\mathbf{X}_{2\times 1}$ is a column vector with $x_1$ and $x_2$ as its elements without any loss of generality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the *$\Bbb F^n$* is isomorphic to $n$-dimensional vector space $\Bbb F^{n\times 1}$, where $\Bbb F$ denotes a field and $\Bbb F^n$ is a vector space of n-tuples and  $\Bbb F^{n\times 1}$ is column matrix i.e of size $n\times 1$ which also a vector space and the isomorphism is natural that is 
$$(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: On a different note, do I need to change the function definition in any way to reflect the change in the input? If so, could you please point out to relevant link. Thanks a bunch for the help.